# Show only 1 error message per field Express-validator

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a basic authentication application using ExpressJs and pug(template) and is working but when authentication fails it shows multiple error message for same field.

Login.pug

```
body
    div.columns

      div.card.column.is-4.is-offset-4
       if(error)
        p.help.is-danger #{error}
       form(action="/account/login",method="post")
         div.card-content
            div.content
               div.field
                 p.control
                   input(type="text", placeholder="Email", name="email").input.is-primary.is-outlined
                   if(errors)
                     for error in errors
                         if (error.param=='email')
                            p.help.is-danger #{error.msg} 

               div.field
                 p.control
                   input(type="password", placeholder="Password", name="password").input.is-primary.is-outlined
                   if(errors)
                      for error in errors
                         if (error.param=='password')
                            p.help.is-danger #{error.msg}



         button(type="submit",align="right").button.is-primary.is-outlined.is-pulled-right Login
```

Route (account.js)

```
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email must be valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password must be 8-16 characters long').isLength(8);
var errors = req.validationErrors();
if (errors) {
    res.render('login', { errors: errors });
}
```

[image]

What I want is to show single error message for the single field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to my own question

Just added `-break` inside the loop results in printing only 1 message like-

```
if(errors)
   for error in errors
     if (error.param=='email')
        p.help.is-danger #{error.msg} 
        -break
```